# Creating an auto-incrementing column for a large table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to add a new column (column_id) into an existing table in Oracle SQL Dev. I need it to be auto-incrementing (starting from 1). The problem is that the table contains around 300 million records, and I am not finding an efficient way of populating the column.

After all my attempts, all the methods run for 2-3 hours and then fails to execute what I want. Can you please help me with an efficient way for populating the column with more than 300 million records? (Note: I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition)

I tried 3 ways: (1) using IDENTITY, (2) using a sequence, (3) and using both sequence and trigger, and then inserting the records from the beginning.

First method:

```
ALTER TABLE PARTICIPANTS_TABLE
ADD COLUMN_ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
```

Second method:

```
CREATE SEQUECE SEQ_PARTICIPANTS
MIN VALUE 1
MAX VALUE 400000000
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1
CACHE 10000;

 /* HERE I PRE-ADDED THE column_id WITHOUT POPULATING IT AND THEN UPDATED IT */

UPDATE PARTICIPANTS_TABLE
SET COLUMN_ID = SEQ_PARTICIPANTS.NEXTVAL;
```

Third method:

```
/* Firstly creating a trigger, then re-creating an empty table and populating it with 300 million records so that the column_id would be filled by the trigger */

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIG_PARTICIPANTS
BEFORE INSERT
ON PARTICIPANTS_TABLE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF(:NEW.COLUMN_ID IS NULL) THEN
   SELECT SEQ_PARTICIPANTS.NEXTVALUE
   INTO :NEW.COLUMN_ID
   FROM DUAL
   END IF
END;
```

Comment: Can you retry with `ALTER TABLE participants_table ADD column_id INT DEFAULT seq_participants.nextval` just to populate without cost of any constraint.

Comment: I would copy the data to a new table, as inserts are less resource-intensive than updates, especially if you can use direct path with nologging.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I just tried your suggestion, but I am getting the same error as before: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS1'.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I have already tried that, still no result.

Comment: Could you process by chunck (of the same size as the sequence cache)?

Comment: @p3consulting Can you help me by showing in code what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean, "no result"? I've done a lot of table rebuilds and never had "no result". What did you try exactly, and what happened exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BEGIN 
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            UPDATE PARTICIPANTS_TABLE
            SET COLUMN_ID = SEQ_PARTICIPANTS.NEXTVAL
            WHERE rowid in (
                SELECT rowid FROM PARTICIPANTS_TABLE WHERE COLUMN_ID IS NULL
                OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10000 ROWS ONLY
            ) ;
            EXIT WHEN SQL%rowcount = 0 ;
            COMMIT ;
        END ;
    END LOOP ;  
END ;
```